# How does wood compare to coal in terms of home heating efficiency?

Tags: banished

How much more efficient is coal as a fuel compared to coal? Does the increase in efficiency warrant switching from wood to coal?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search yielded this:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Banished/comments/20b7gi/firewood_vs_coal_heating_some_numbers_or_wtf/

The essence of the post there is that there is no difference between coal and firewood heating, except coal being harder to obtain, of course.

Keep in mind that this was 4 months ago.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers without sumarizing the information found in the link.

Comment: Fixed that right up. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

as i remember. wood gives only 1 heat. while coal gives 1.5

so coals have 50% more efficient than wood.